# use snprintf in printing integer values

Tags: c, integer, printf

The code below is converting a number of seconds to the `DD:HH:MM` format. Instead of using `printf`, I would like to use `snprintf`. How should I print those d,h,m in the `snprintf`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LONGEST 60

int main() {
    int sec, h, m, s, d, temp; 
    char *temp_str;
    int test= 2835656; 
    d = test / 86400; //divide the number of seconds by the number of seconds in a day
    if (d < 100) {
        temp = test % 86400; 
        temp /= 60;  // 
        h = temp / 60; //to get "minute" 
        m = temp % 60; //to get "second"
    } else {
        d = 99;
        h = 23;
        m = 59;
    }

    printf("DD:HH:MM:%d:%d:%d\n", d, h, m); //output is DD:HH:MM:32:19:40

    return 0;
}
```

I tried `snprintf(temp_str, LONGEST, "%02s:%02s:%02s", d, h, m);` but it didn't work

Comment: __Q:__ _How should I print those d,h,m in the snprintf?_ A: _the same way as with `printf`_.

Comment: "but it didn't work" is not a very useful statement unless the problem is as simple as in this case. How does it not work. Does your compile shout warnings about type mismatch at you? I hope so. Does it print garbage? Probably yes. You need to tell us what exactly is your problem

Comment: The nice thing about `snprintf` is that you can tell it how big the destination buffer is.  So when you call `snprintf(temp_str, LONGEST, ...)`, normally that constant `LONGEST` is the size of the buffer `temp_str`, either the size of the array if it's an array, or the size you asked for with `malloc()` if it's a pointer.  So: where's the other place in your program where you used `LONGEST` to set the size of the buffer?

Answer (score 3):

Why the different format string for the `snprintf` attempt? Just do it like you did in the `printf` call:

```
snprintf(temp_str, LONGEST, "DD:HH:MM:%d:%d:%d", d, h, m);
```

The `%02s` specifier doesn't work for integers. You also haven't declared `temp_str`, so you need to do that beforehand:

```
char temp_str[LONGEST];
```

After calling `snprintf`, the string `"DD:HH:MM:32:19:40"` is stored in `temp_str` and you can verify that with `puts(temp_str);`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You must define `temp_str` as an array of `char` with at least `LONGEST` elements, andd you can use the same format string as for `printf`.

Note however that your format string should be `"%02d:%02d:%02d"` to produce 2 digits for each field even for values below `10`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define LONGEST 60

int main() {
    int sec, h, m, s, d, temp; 
    char temp_str[LONGEST];
    int test = 2835656;

    d = test / 86400; //divide the number of seconds by the number of seconds in a day
    if (d < 100) {
        temp = test % 86400; 
        temp /= 60;    // discard the seconds
        h = temp / 60; // to get "hour" 
        m = temp % 60; // to get "minute"
    } else {
        d = 99;
        h = 23;
        m = 59;
    }

    snprintf(temp_str, LONGEST, "DD:HH:MM:%02d:%02d:%02d\n", d, h, m); //output is DD:HH:MM:32:19:40
    fputs(temp_str, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```